# Permission for specific document libraries only

Tags: permissions, document-library

I have a user (or group) without any permission on a site. I break inheritance on a document library and give that user permission on the library. Now, if the user navigates to the document library, he also sees Quick Launch links to all other lists and can navigate to those lists. The only solution I have is to specifically remove the user from each list on the site.

Is there a way to give a user or group permission on specific document libraries only?

Also, if it is a security requirement to hide the lists and names of other document libraries, is assigning permissions at this level a recommended solution? Or, should I be handling this is another way?

Comment: I agree with Laurie. I tested on SharePoint 2010 trying to resolve the same issue. If user is setup to access only ONE library/list, the user can also see all the other site content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This unfortunately is by design. Read [this article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/permission-levels-and-permissions-HA010100149.aspx).

"*The Limited Access permission level is designed to be combined with fine-grained permissions to give users access to a specific list, document library, item, or document, without giving them access to the entire site. However, to access a list or library, for example, a user must have permission to open the parent Web site and read shared data such as the theme and navigation bars of the Web site. The Limited Access permission level cannot be customized or deleted.*"

So, by giving a user only access to a specific document library, you also give the user limited access to the site. This means they get to see the navigation with lists. However, they **don't** get to see the contents!

I'm not familiar with another way to realize this, except to stop inheriting permissions for each list and remove the user from that list.

Comment: I have found that as soon as the user receives Limited Access, he can not only see lists, but he can view the items in the list. This behavior is different with a document library.

Comment: Laurie, I've tested this in SP2010 by giving reading permissions to a document library. The user then had limited right on other lists but could not see the listitems. Please check again ;-)

Comment: Laurie, please check if the user is in another SP or AD group which has permissions on other lists.

Comment: This is in a MOSS2007 environment using the Collaboration Portal template and an FBA user, but I wouldn't think that this would make a difference. I am almost 100% sure he is not in any other groups other than the one given the Limited Access permission, but I will check that.